# Kubernetes: executable mounted through hostPath fails with found error

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to run docker from my pod to launch docker containers (docker inside k8s). To get docker images from the host I am mounting docker.sock and docker command in my pod through hostPath. Even though I find the files mounted I cannot execute the docker command, it will fail with command not found error.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: alphine
  labels:
    app: alphine
spec:
  containers:
  - name: alpine
    image: alpine
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
    volumeMounts:
    - name: tmp
      mountPath: /tmp
    - name: docker-sock
      mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
    - name: docker-cmd  # docker command from host.
      mountPath: /usr/bin/docker
    - name: lib64  # for running docker from the host.
      mountPath: /lib64
      readOnly: true
    - name: usr-lib64  # for running docker from the host.
      mountPath: /usr/lib64
      readOnly: true
    command: ["sleep", "infinity"]
  volumes:
  - name: tmp
    emptyDir: {}
  - name: docker-cmd
    hostPath:
      path: /usr/bin/docker
      type: File
  - name: lib64
    hostPath:
      path: /lib64
      type: Directory
  - name: usr-lib64
    hostPath:
      path: /usr/lib64
      type: Directory
  - name: docker-sock
    hostPath:
      path: /var/run/docker.sock
      type: Socket
```

I am staring minikube with below command

```
minikube start --memory=16g --cpus=2 --disk-size=10g \
  -p mycluster \
  --extra-config=apiserver.enable-admission-plugins=PodSecurityPolicy \
  --addons=pod-security-policy --wait=all
```

The same does work in Docker in Docker environment. Where I will start my container with below command

```
 docker create
      --name=mypod
      --read-only
      --restart=on-failure
      -v /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker:ro
      -v /lib64:/lib64:ro
      -v /usr/lib64:/usr/lib64:ro
      -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      alphine

docker start mypod
```

Am I missing something here? Any pointers/reference is appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you need to launch additional containers, use the Kubernetes API to do it.  Trying to mix Docker commands on a Kubernetes-managed node isn't guaranteed to work reliably.  Injecting host commands like you've shown doesn't work reliably even in plain Docker, and in Kubernetes you can't be guaranteed that every node will have the same versions of the same binaries in the same places (in general, don't use `hostPath` volumes at all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a difference in guest OS. I tried `Ubuntu:latest` instead `alpine` as my guest image and I was able to access the docker command from my guest.

Not sure if there is any security difference between these 2 guest OS

Answer (score 1):

The hostPath of your minikube cluster isn't the same as your local machine. When you run the `docker` command on your local machine, it uses the hostPath of your machine where the files/directory exists. But these files/directories don't exist inside the minkube cluster node.

**Solution:**

1. Create a Dockerfile and copy the files/directories while building the image:

```
FROM alphine:latest
COPY /var/run/docker.sock /var/run/docker.sock
... ...
... ...
CMD ["sleep", "infinity"]
```

2. Use this image in your pod:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: alphine
  labels:
    app: alphine
spec:
  containers:
  - name: your_image
    image: your_image:latest
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
```